# How do you clone a jQuery UI checkbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

I am building a form dynamically.  I rename the id tags of the inputs to specific values (so I can reference them later).  When I include a checkbox input, I end up with a radio set (or at least strange behavior) vs. individual checkboxes.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun5/ms163u6L/1/) to illustrate the problem...

**HTML**

```
<div id='first'>     
    <input type="checkbox" id="some-0"><label for="some-0">My Label</label></input>
</div>
<div id='second'>
 <input type="checkbox" id="some-1"><label for="some-1">My Label</label></input>   
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('[id^=some]').button();
var temp = $('#second').clone(true);
temp.find('input').each(function (){
    var NAME = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    var LINEcount = 2;
    $(this).attr('id',NAME[0]+'-'+LINEcount);
});
$('body').append(temp);
```

Comment: It looks like your clone function is copying the onClick listener, which would explain why it toggles both buttons.

Comment: I found even more odd behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/shaun5/ms163u6L/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe your issue doesn't lie on the `clone` function, instead on the `button` function. You need to change the `for` attribute in the `<label>` also. Try to use below code:

```
$('[id^=some]').button();
var temp = $('#second').clone(true);
temp.find('input').each(function (){
    var NAME = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    var LINEcount = 2;
    $(this).attr('id',NAME[0]+'-'+LINEcount);
    $(this).next().attr('for',NAME[0]+'-'+LINEcount);
});
$('body').append(temp);
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ms163u6L/4/)..

Comment: Thanks.  This was a good idea, but ultimately still only 50% of the solution (at least within my code). If you destroy the jQuery UI button and then reinitiate it afterwards it works within my code.  My test of trying to destroy all the UI buttons works as well with this approach... http://jsfiddle.net/shaun5/ms163u6L/5/

Answer (score 0):

I hope that one help you [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ms163u6L/3/)
I make that in a click event .. you can change it with event you want I add class to your primary divs and change first and seconds to top-div-1 and top-div-2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thisDiv > input').button();
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
        var count = ($('.thisDiv').length) +1;
        $('body').append('<div class="thisDiv" id="top-div-'+count+'"><input type="checkbox" id="some-'+count+'"><label for="some-'+count+'">My Label '+count+'</label></input</div>');
            $('.thisDiv > input').button();
    });
});
```

If that what you looking for??  for any help I'm here

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've simplified my code greatly to ask the question. Abandoning the jQuery UI for the checkbox is easier vs. trying to make exceptions for all the checkboxes (and is what I have temporarily done), but I still would like to find a solution using clone...

Answer (score 0):

```
var clone=$("#original_object").clone( true );

clone.appendTo("#new_parent");
```